# Create new columns in dataframe which are dependent on previous values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I would like to create two additional columns in my dataframe, which depend on both existing data in the dataframe and data which will be created in the two new rows.

If Open_Flag[i] = 1 then the first new column, Open_Value[i] = 1000 and, the second new column, Close_Value[i] = Open_Value * Change

If Open_Flag[i] = 0 then the first new column, Open Value[i] = Close_Value[i-1] (previous close value)

My issue is that I cannot figure out who to write a for loop which will do this.

```
        data = {'Date': ['2023-03-05', '2023-03-06', '2023-03-07', '2023-03-05', '2023-03-06', '2023-03-07'],
            'Name': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
            'Change': [.9, .8, .96, .97, 1.3, 1.5],
            'Open_Flag':[1,0,0,1,0,0]}
    
    
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    

for i in range(len(df.Open_Flag)):
    if df.loc[i, 'Open_Flag'] == 1:
        df.loc[i, 'Open_Value'] = 1000 and df.loc[i, 'Close_Value'] = df[i,'Open_Value'] * df[i,'AlphaPicks Open Close Daily Return_R Script']
    elif df.loc[i, 'pos'] == 1:
        df.loc[i+1, 'pos'] = df.loc[i, 'pos'] + df.loc[i, 'above_hi']

print(df)
```

Here is my desired Output

```
         Date Name  Change  Open_Flag  Open_Value  Close_Value
0  2023-03-05  abc    0.90          1        1000        900.0
1  2023-03-06  abc    0.80          0         900        720.0
2  2023-03-07  abc    0.96          0         720        691.2
3  2023-03-05  xyz    0.97          1        1000        970.0
4  2023-03-06  xyz    1.30          0         970       1261.0
5  2023-03-07  xyz    1.50          0        1261       1891.5
```

When I try to run my incorrect for loop I get the following error:

> File "", line 3
> df.loc[i, 'Open_Value'] = 1000 and df.loc[i, 'Close_Value'] = df[i,'Open_Value'] * df[i,'AlphaPicks Open Close Daily Return_R Script']
> ^
> SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator

How can I fix this to get my desired output?

Comment: There's no need for a for loop here. Look up the Pandas `where` function to get started.

Comment: Where function doesn't work because there is dependency on values that don't exist yet.

Comment: Just make your new column and fill it with some initial value (1000, for example), then use `where` to change it for the cases where that's not the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
g = df.groupby(df['Open_Flag'].cumsum())

df['Open_Value'] = g.apply(lambda x: (x['Change'].cumprod() * 1000).shift().fillna(1000)).values
df['Close_Value'] = g.apply(lambda x: x['Change'].cumprod() * 1000).values

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date Name  Change  Open_Flag  Open_Value  Close_Value
0  2023-03-05  abc    0.90          1      1000.0        900.0
1  2023-03-06  abc    0.80          0       900.0        720.0
2  2023-03-07  abc    0.96          0       720.0        691.2
3  2023-03-05  xyz    0.97          1      1000.0        970.0
4  2023-03-06  xyz    1.30          0       970.0       1261.0
5  2023-03-07  xyz    1.50          0      1261.0       1891.5
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked! Why did you decide to use a lambda function and not for loop? Just trying to get the logic in my head.

Comment: @ZacharyMarx When I look at your data, you want to do cumulative product and pandas has the function for it ready `.cumprod()`. The main "problem" is only to find the groups where to apply this function - hence the `df.groupby(df['Open_Flag'].cumsum())`.